# How can I do Substract Time in MySQL Query, using format (HH:mm:ss)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, timestamp

`timestart` = 16:46:33

`timeend` = 16:48:22

Expected Result = 00:01:49

My Query:

```
Select timestart , timeend, (timeend - timestart) as rangetime from time;
```

Comment: Check out the official docs for time functions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Check MySQL [**TIMEDIFF**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function.

Try this:

```
SELECT timestart, timeend, TIMEDIFF(timeend, timestart) AS rangetime 
FROM time;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [**SubTime**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime)

```
Select timestart , timeend, SUBTIME(timestart ,timeend) As rangetime from time;
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/39398)**

Answer (score 0):

```
select Timestart,Timeend,subtime(Timestart,Timeend) as rangetime from time;
```

[More Info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime)

Answer (score 0):

Check **[TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)** function

Try this

```
    SELECT timestart,
       timeend,
       TIMEDIFF(timeend,timestart) AS rangetime
FROM `time`;
```